# nVidia Xavier gstreamer error (CSI camera)

Tags: camera, gstreamer, nvidia, v4l2, csi

I tried to cpature and stream images from a CSI camera with nVidia Xavier using gstreamer.
My command is :

`$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! "video/x-bayer, format=(string)bggr, width=(int)3840, height=(int)2162, framerate=(fraction)30/1" ! bayer2rgb ! videoconvert ! autovideosink -ev --gst-debug=3` 
but, got the following message.

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayX11\)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:00.346056224  4279 0xaaab000e0b60 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3072:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.346136032  4279 0xaaab000e0b60 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3072:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
EOS on shutdown enabled -- waiting for EOS after Error
Waiting for EOS...
```

What's wrong?

`$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! "video/x-bayer, format=(string)bggr, width=(int)3840, height=(int)2162, framerate=(fraction)30/1" ! bayer2rgb ! videoconvert ! autovideosink -ev --gst-debug=3`

I want to see Preview from camera.

Comment: can you up your debug level to 4 or 5. It looks to me like your camera is not being mounted and no content is arriving which is moving the pipeline back from PLAYING to PAUSED